# Output a network share location to the Console with Write-Host

Tags: powershell

I have the following code:

```
$exclude = 'Remote Admin', 'Remote IPC', 'Default share'
$shared  = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share |
       Where-Object { $exclude -notcontains $_.Description } |
       Select-Object -Expand Path

$FilesToSearch = Get-ChildItem $shared -Filter '*_HELP_instructions*' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If($FilesToSearch -ne $null) 

{
Write-Host "System Infected!" 
exit 2015
}

else 

{
Write-Host "System Clear!" 
exit 0
}
```

Essentially is scans through all shares on a local Server for any files with *_HELP_instructions* in the filename.

If it finds a file matching this name it outputs "System Infected!" to the console and exits the script with a specific code.

What i would like it to do is to actually detail the share location that is infected and output that to the Console. The output would look something like "Network Share E:\Data\Clients is Infected!".

Can this be achieved please?

Many thanks

Comment: `$FilesToSearch` if not null should contain the files. you could just output that variable which should be an array of the infected file paths.

Comment: Hi Nkosi - so the line of code would be:
    
    {
    Write-Host "Network Share" $FilesToSearch "is Infected!"
    exit 2015
    }

Would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$FilesToSearch is an array with files you find.
so to achieve what you want:

```
If($FilesToSearch -ne $null) 
{
    foreach ($file in $FilesToSearch){
        Write-Host "System Infected! Directory:" $file.DirectoryName
    } 
    exit 2015
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, worked a treat. Both solutions gave me the result i was after although this solution just detailed the shares and not the individual files and so was a marginally better solution for my needs